# The Google Cloud Extension Package package did not load correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2017, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tools

I am having an issue with VS2017 and Google Cloud toolbar. It used to work before and now I am getting this pop up every time I open VS2017.

> The 'GoogleCloudExtensionPackage' package did not load correctly. The
>   problem may have been caused by a configuration change or but the
>   installation of another extension. You can get more information by
>   examing the files
>   '...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxxxxxx\ActivityLog.xml'.
>   Restarting Visual Studio could help resolve this issue.

Publish to Google Cloud option is also disabled. Tried reinstalling extension and VS. No matter how many times I restart, re-install, repair, anything it doesn't work.  Activity Log shows the following error

```
LegacySitePackage failed for package [GoogleCloudExtensionPackage]
Source: 'mscorlib' Description: An item with the same key has already been added. 
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. 
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) 
  at GoogleCloudExtension.Accounts.CredentialsStore.LoadAccounts() at GoogleCloudExtension.Accounts.CredentialsStore..ctor() 
  at GoogleCloudExtension.Accounts.CredentialsStore.<>c.<.cctor>b__67_0() 
  at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() 
  at System.Lazy`1.get_Value() 
  at GoogleCloudExtension.Accounts.CredentialsStore.get_Default() 
  at GoogleCloudExtension.GoogleCloudExtensionPackage.Initialize() 
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)
```

I also tried deleting the below folders

- C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0xxxxx
- C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0xxxxx

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue was reported to the extension developers on Github, [see here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-visualstudio/issues/1064). As you can see on [this comment](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-visualstudio/issues/1064#issuecomment-414747544) this issue was caused by multiple user account files linked to one user account, and should be fixed by deleting the offending files:

> Go to %LOCALAPPDATA%\googlecloudvsextension\accounts and you will find several *.json files. Deleting them all (or just the ones with duplicate accounts) should fix this issue.